# RewriteCond for multiple files

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, rewritecond

In htaccess file, RewriteCond for one file `bla.php` can write so right?

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !bla.php
```

Question: how can write RewriteCond for multiple files? for example for 3 files: `bla.php`, `some_bla.php`,`some_other_bla.php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mod_rewrite you can chain more conditions - by default they are connected by logical AND but you can change in with rewritecond's switch OR like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !bla.php [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !somebla.php
```